# How to restore deleted wordpress site?

Tags: customization

Is it possible to restore deleted wordpress sites? Before delete, the data was exported into couple of XMLs. What is the process to restore it on the web? What is the method to view it without making it publicly viewable?

Comment: how you did the export ?  using the native export tool ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to install a blank WordPress install somewhere...locally or on the domain you want to transfer it to and check the "Discourage search engines" option.

Then use WordPress importer to import the content, I assume you only exported all posts and pages?

You'll need to manually set the rest such as Site Name and any other customisation you made.

Basically, anything you exported into XML should be able to import into a blank install.